# Capture parent node id when unique values found in combination

Tags: python-3.x, xml, api, beautifulsoup

I am looking to parse through this API response, :

```
<export_response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cakemarketing.com/api/4/">
  <success>true</success>
  <row_count>3</row_count>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>
            <fruit_id>178</fruit_id>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>231</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>70</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string>CA|NY|AZ</param_string>
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>237</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>90</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string>Poor < 5</param_string>
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </fruit>
         <fruit>
            <fruit_id>178</fruit_id>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>231</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>70</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string>CA|NY|AZ</param_string>
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>237</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>90</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string>Poor < 5</param_string>
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </fruit>
            <fruit>
            <fruit_id>178</fruit_id>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>231</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>70</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string>CA|NY|AZ</param_string>
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                <filter_id>237</filter_id>
                <filter_type>
                <filter_type_id>90</filter_type_id>
                </filter_type>
                <param_number xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_string xsi:nil="true"/> 
                <param_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                <param_bool xsi:nil="true"/>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </fruit>
    </fruits>
</export_response>
```

The goal is to find the fruid_id when <param_string> inside equals 'Poor < 5' and 'CA|NY|AZ'. This should return fruit_id 176 and 178.

I've tried using findall() as well as .find(text='CA|NY|AZ Poor < 5') and I am not able to locate the correct fruit_ids.

Any sugguestions are welcome, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use a combination of :has and :contains, along with use of an adjacent sibling combinator (+) to specify the request pattern. By joining the patterns for both search terms with AND syntax, you select for only where both present. I assume you wanted the unique ids so used a set

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
xml = '''your xml goes here'''
soup = bs(xml, 'lxml')
unique_ids = {i.text for i in soup.select('fruit_id:has(+ filters param_string:contains("Poor < 5")):has(+ filters param_string:contains("CA|NY|AZ"))')}
print(unique_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a 176, but nonetheless here's a way to capture the id and parameters to list, then you can test the list elements and operate on them as needed.

```
# data = your xml from above

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
for f in soup.find_all('fruit'):
    test_list = []
    test_list.append(f.fruit_id.text)
    for ps in f.find_all('filter'):
        test_list.append(ps.find('param_string').text)
    print(test_list)
    # do your validations here.....after each iteration
```

produces:

```
['178', 'CA|NY|AZ', 'Poor < 5']
['178', 'CA|NY|AZ', 'Poor < 5']
['178', 'CA|NY|AZ', '']
```